# CakePHP chmod 775 vs 755

Tags: cakephp

I've got a strange problem. After creating an application (CakePHP v2.4.9) I've deployed it to **virtual server** online. It wasn't working so I went through some steps:

```
chown -R user:group, chmod -R 775, checked for BOM, checked for mod_rewrite etc.
```

I've tried complete new application on server, same steps and nothing. Only **after** `chmod -R 755`, everything worked out.

Now, on a **shared server**, `chmod -R 775` works great. What could cause this behavior? As far I can tell, `755` are less permissions than `775`. Even `chmod -R 777` wasn't the solution, only `755` was.

Virtual server PHP version: 5.4.27

Shared server PHP version: 4.4.9

Comment: If you define "wasn't working" it might be possible to say what the problem was. "The problem" will also be in the apache and/or application log files.

Comment: Well, now it's not possible for me to get the logs (maybe in a few days) but I was just getting HTTP 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some servers are configured to not run files with permissions that are too open. Especially on shared hosting.